# How to use name_get in odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

Good day,
Am trying to use name_get function but it is giving me **Internal Server Error** Below is my code

```
class DrugsList(models.Model):
    _name = 'hms.drugs.list'
    _rec_name = 'drug_name'
        

    name = fields.Char(string='DoC Drug Identifier', default='/', help='Identifier provided by DOC.', copy=True, tracking=True)
    drug_name = fields.Char(tracking=True)
    default_code = fields.Char(string='Nappi Code', required=True)
    
    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        res = []
        for rec in self:
            res.append((rec.id, "%s, %s" % (rec.default_code, rec.drug_name)))
        return res



    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
      if values.get('name','/')=='/':
           values['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('hms.drugs.list') or ''
       return super(DrugsList, self).create(values)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [@api.multi](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/4b38cc6590abcb58a0ca102a06063eb3db7ac1f4#diff-6b27f146b1eec6bfa1d9d1d8b12af99e9ff01323bd7cd2841cb4fc72a30afe44) decorator is no longer available. You must remove it.

You should see the following error message in the server log:

```
AttributeError: module 'odoo.api' has no attribute 'multi'
```

You can check an example in [sale](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/sale/models/sale.py#L541) module without the `multi` decorator or another in [account](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L2037) using the `depends` decorator.